# Java: Parse String with starts with 0 sometimes

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a `String` to `Long` which sometimes starts with `0`. I want that the result maintains the `"0"` at the beginning of the Long (e.g. `0247484` instead of `247484`).

I have tried this `Long.parseLong(city.getId())` but it deletes the first `"0"`.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, just as @devnull said... Use `Formatter`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, and how will this help you solve it?

Comment: That's a nonsense. Long represents a number. You cannot store any redundant character there. If you did, how would you implement equals() for example?

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is not possible. In mathematical terms the leading 0 is absolutely meaningless so there is no way to represent it in a long.

What you probably want to do is control the rendering of the Long when you later print it out. There are all sorts of ways to control the formatting of a number, this may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use the DecimalFormat class:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

```
String number = "0247484";

long parsed = Long.parseLong(number);
System.out.println("Unformatted: " + parsed);

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000000");
String formatted = df.format(parsed);

System.out.println("Formatted: " + formatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really need, you can do sth like that:

for example : 08530(string) to long ==> 8530 when you need to convert another time String, 
you can do :

```
String.format("%05d", number);
```

but you need to define a pattern. I hope it helps.